# problem when using css file to responsive html file, when minimizing the screen images are stuck together

Tags: html, css

I am newbie with html css and here is my problem. I coded a very simple html and css file and here is my problem.

First, I coded a html file and a css file as you can see here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./grid.css">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="grid wide container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col l-3 m-6 c-12">
<div class="course-item">
<h1>course 1</h1>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col l-3 m-6 c-12">
<div class="course-item">
<h1>course 2</h1>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col l-3 m-6 c-12">
<div class="course-item">
<h1>course 3</h1>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col l-3 m-6 c-12">
<div class="course-item">
<h1>course 4</h1>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a css file, sorry I must upload to this because it is too long

https://www.mediafire.com/file/bufxtqr82ewrjiu/grid.css/file

My problem is, when I use this code, it worked very ok, as you can see in these pictures,
at resolution /* >= Tablet */, i use m-6 and it display 2 columns above, 2 columns underground [image: tablet]

at resolution c-12, it display only 1 column and the column take up all the space as you can see in this picture [image: c-12]

because I set c-12 is

```
.c-12 {
flex: 0 0 100%;
max-width: 100%;
}
```

But, my problem is, when I add this code to the css file :

```
.course-item {
background-color: orange;
height: 260px;
width: 260px;
}
```

And remove the code /*background-color: #ccc;*/ at .col

It became like this, when I tried to test the resolution for the tablet, the display of the image being stuck together as you can see in this picture[image: picture about problem 1]

and when I minimize the screen, the the column did not take up all the space as you can see in this picture[image: picture about problem 2]

About problem 2, I does not know why ? Because I set at c-12 here as you can see in the code

```
.c-12 {
flex: 0 0 100%;
max-width: 100%;
}
```

so it must take all the space ?

Could you please help me to solve this problem ? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: remove `height and width` of `.course-item`

Comment: as @AmanSharma mentioned. it happens because you set your width and height to a static value. I think what you want is to get height only. so remove only width from `.course-item{...}` and whenever you want to share lengthy code try using [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/) so that we can help effectively and easily.

Comment: @ækit: thank you, exactly what I need to do, and Amn Sharma too, thank for your comment, your comment are so great